# MDX parameter with Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: parameter-passing, mdx, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I would like to add a parameter to my main report MDX query in Pentaho Report Designer but I'm a novice with MDX.  I have tried adding the parameter to the where clause at the end of the statement but have not had much luck.  The parameter was created in Report Designer and the name is **p_bod_is**.  The member that needs to be set is [GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt] which is the value of the parameter.  My original MDX query is as follows:

```
WITH
SET [*NATIVE_CJ_SET_WITH_SLICER] AS '[*BASE_MEMBERS__GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt_]'
SET [*NATIVE_CJ_SET] AS '[*NATIVE_CJ_SET_WITH_SLICER]'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__Measures_] AS '{[Measures].[*ZERO]}'
SET [*CJ_ROW_AXIS] AS 'GENERATE([*NATIVE_CJ_SET], {([GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt].CURRENTMEMBER)})'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt_] AS '[GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt].[GL Account BOD Inc Stmt].MEMBERS'
SET [*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] AS 'ORDER([*CJ_ROW_AXIS],[GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt].CURRENTMEMBER.ORDERKEY,BASC)'
SELECT
[*BASE_MEMBERS__Measures_] ON COLUMNS
,[*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] ON ROWS
FROM [GL]
```

My attempt is here:

```
WITH
SET [*NATIVE_CJ_SET_WITH_SLICER] AS '[*BASE_MEMBERS__GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt_]'
SET [*NATIVE_CJ_SET] AS '[*NATIVE_CJ_SET_WITH_SLICER]'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__Measures_] AS '{[Measures].[*ZERO]}'
SET [*CJ_ROW_AXIS] AS 'GENERATE([*NATIVE_CJ_SET], {([GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt].CURRENTMEMBER)})'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt_] AS '{[GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt].[${p_bod_is}]}'
SET [*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] AS 'ORDER([*CJ_ROW_AXIS],[GL Account.GL Account BOD Inc Stmt].CURRENTMEMBER.ORDERKEY,BASC)'
SELECT
[*BASE_MEMBERS__Measures_] ON COLUMNS
,[*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] ON ROWS
FROM [GL]
```

The query executes but with no results, and the parameter is not working.

Comment: So, the report generates successfully, just the details are empty? Can you try following query just to check what value is passed: `WITH MEMBER [Measures].test AS "Value: [" || "${p_bod_is}" || "]." SELECT [Measures].test ON 0 FROM [GL]`? If the report fails, then I'd suggest to look into reporting and mondrian logs.

Comment: After further review I found that the issue was with the corresponding MDX parameter as well as a missing bracket in my query above.  Thank you.